# Accidental overwrite of OSX Python system framework

Tags: python, macos, frameworks, osx-leopard

I got ahead of myself and downloaded and installed the OSX Python 2.6 package from www.python.org/download/ on my OSX 10.5.5 Intel Mac and installed the full package contents. Only after this did I come across http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/Leopard stating that you should do a partial install of the package to avoid interfering with the system install.

I'm afraid I've already overwritten the system framework through that installer and I remember reading somewhere after discovering this that I'd lose certain elements included in the OSX system install and not Python distributions.

Is there any way to reverse this or restore anything I may have lost? What exactly have I lost and is it going to be a problem?

Answer (score 5):

You may have overwritten the system framework but it is more likely that you just overwrote the symlinks in `/usr/bin` to point to the new version.  Try going to `/usr/bin` and seeing (with something like `ls -alsh`) where the `python` symlink points to.  It may be `python2.6` or `3.0`, which is in turn a ln to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions ...` etc.  First try resetting the python symlink to the stable or expected version, ie, `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.5 python` (from the `/usr/bin` dir.)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same thing myself. I did find that the MacPython installer modified my search $PATH and added '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin' which caused the python executable there to be found before the one in '/usr/bin'.

Hope this helps anyone else!

Answer (score -1):

Restore from a recent Time Machine backup or somehow from DVD?